# Detecting Alpha waves in EEG data through SNR? python

Tags: python, math, pycharm, signal-processing

I am writing a function that detect Alpha waves in real time. My function receives 256 sample values of single channel as an argument.
After that its fft has to be found and then classified in alpha , beta and gamma ranges. Then I have to find SNR to check whether at alpha waves are present or not i.e is there any peak that exists at 10 hz frequency. So i need to find square of amplitude of values at 10hz divided by sum of square of all values in b/w range of 8-12hz divided by N values.

SNR = Square of Amp Value at 10hz/ (Square of rest values in 8-12hz / No. of these values)

Then 20 log SNR and check threshold.

So basically how to get square of Amp of values that are at 10 hz and then exclude this value and divided by rest of values.

I have written kick starter code below can someone guide or help to complete the code to get the desired job done.
Many thanks.

def classification(flag, data=[]):

```
fs = 200  # Sampling rate (512 Hz)


# Get real amplitudes of FFT (only in postive frequencies)
fft_vals = np.absolute(np.fft.rfft(data))    #these are my fft values rfft returns only the part of the result that corresponds to nonpositive frequences. (Avoids complex conjugaes) faster and for plotting

# Get frequencies for amplitudes in Hz
fft_freq = np.fft.rfftfreq(len(data), 1.0 / fs)     # that might be fixed (window length n , and  sample spacing) inverse of the sampling rate   returns sample freq of length n .

# Define EEG bands
eeg_bands = {'Delta': (0, 4),
             'Theta': (4, 8),
             'Alpha': (8, 12),
             'Beta': (12, 30),
             'Gamma': (30, 45)}

# Take the mean of the fft amplitude for each EEG band
eeg_band_fft = dict()
for band in eeg_bands:
    freq_ix = np.where((fft_freq >= eeg_bands[band][0]) &   #np.where is like asking "tell me where in this array, entries satisfy a given condition".
                       (fft_freq <= eeg_bands[band][1]))[0]    #for fft_frreq at all point where it satisfies it returns the index (in array)
                                                             #if fftfreq[np.where bla bla] will give values array
    eeg_band_fft[band] = np.mean(fft_vals[freq_ix])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is already extracting the alpha frequencies using band-pass filter. Now to find SNR at specific frequency you simply sum square the values at that frequency divided by rest of frequncies and take 20 log of the division.